# http walmart site page resource block - hack?

Tags: html, browser, malware

I encountered a hostageware webpage today. I use a program call Free Download Manager. Just before the hack, I got an offer to add a Chrome extension for the software. I installed and immediately got the hostage-ware with username and password text boxes. After breaking out of the loop, I began to have problems with Walmart's website. I inspected the page and found the css files Walmart uses are being blocked. This happens with each of five browsers I've tried. The specific message is:
"Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" and occurs for resource files such as images, css and javascript. An unformatted page is what comes up.
   If I empty the cache, closed the page and reboot, the first time I access the website, the page is fine. But as soon as I click something, the formatting of the destination disappears and a back button to the first page reveals that, too, has been unformatted. I haven't figured if this is part of the attack or a side effect. The common url is : "https://us-i5.tb.wal.co". I opened up the url and got the "refused to connect" message. I checked, and all browsers are allowed through the firewall. I went through the registry and removed any entries with Walmart in them and searched for the rejecting url with no luck. I also deleted all the caches. There is something I can do to reset the mechanism, but trigger it when I click on a button in the page, not sure what, though. Update. Removed the extension from all browsers but IExplorer and Opera. Opera did not show the extension as installed. Removed all browsers but IExplorer and Firefox. IExplorer still has the problem, Firefox does not. Since IExplorer is still effected, Re-installing Windows 10 is the most likely next step. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The hostage-ware is using a VPN (from my experience, this protects it). I am no expert in this field but I have my fair share of viruses. A simple solution would be to rollback your PC. You can also check VPN settings to see if there are any settings being tampered with.

Comment: I was using a browser's VPN when the incident happened. I've since turned the VPN off. What settings would the VPN effect?

Comment: @JimJulian from my knowledge, it would probably block and disrupt some of your internet related services

Comment: Seems that would have to be a browser specific issue since, after deleting all instance of the extension and all browsers, except Firefox and IE, Firefox did not have the problem.

Comment: @JimJulian yea gotcha. Not sure how the extension or adware worked. So you solved the problem?

Comment: Not exactly, but close enough. I'm going to do a partial install of Windows 10. Refreshing system files for the most part, I think. I'm using the Firefox browser. I never use IE anyway. I'm pretty sure if I reinstall the other browsers, they will work, but since I don't really need them, I'll shelve that idea.